# Easiest way to cast pivot table in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel

What the easiest way to cast pivot table in Laravel?

```
Class Product{
   public function sales(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(Sale::class)
                  ->withPivot('qty', 'price');
   }
}
```

when I return that price is string, I need to change to int.

Comment: How about using PhP's `intval()` in the view?

Comment: How about if I use this for API too?

Comment: If you mean in the `Price`model, yes why not. Post your model please

Comment: Model(Product, Sale), price just column